# Angular Route partial wildcard

Tags: angular, routes

When a link comes in like this: `mysite.com/_/somethingThatChangesRandomly`

I wish to redirect that to the login page, so the rule is "path starts with _":

```
{
    path: '_/**', redirectTo: "login"
}
```

but I get an error:

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '_/somethingThatChangesRandomly'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
 path: '_',
 children: [
   {
     path: "**",
     redirectTo: "/login"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please include a textual explanation of how and why this solves the problem in the question.

Comment: Include explanation

Comment: This is difficult without context.